# Styling Input and button - height issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to setup a clean CSS to style a button to visually looks merged with the near input field.

[image: example]

I'm using this CSS currently:

```
button {
    position: relative;
    left: -4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GRwqL/

The main problem is the usage of the **`left`** property, I don't think it's a good practice, mostly because it's not handled correctly on all browsers.
The other problem is that this code in Internet Explorer and Firefox makes the button not high as the input field.

So I was looking for some help to write a better code cross-browser and cleaner.
Personally I don't care if is needed a wrapper element or any other HTML element, I just need a clean code, cross browser and that works well.

Comment: _"mostly because it's not handled correctly on all browsers."_ Which browsers would that be?

Comment: Almost on each browser the button is some pixel shifted from the right position. On Chrome are needed 3 px, on Firefox just 1.

Comment: Take a look at bootstrap "Prepended and appended inputs" 
Source : http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use Bootstrap and I'm looking just for a simple CSS to fix this problem, the answer marked as correct do provides a good workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
<span class="inputWithButton">
  <input type="text"><button>Submit</button>
</span>
```

```
 input, button{outline: none;}

.inputWithButton{
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.inputWithButton > *{
    vertical-align:top;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding: 3px 10px;
}
.inputWithButton > input[type=text]{
    width:150px;
}
.inputWithButton > button{
    border-left:1px solid gray;
    background:#eee;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:70px;
}
.inputWithButton > button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
```

DEMO with higher paddings and different borders colors : http://jsbin.com/OPiroyib/4/edit

[image]

<sup>(Just remove border from the `span` and **add border to both input and button**) That easy.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Does it have some advantage compared to the answer I've set as correct? (except the ie8- compatibility)

Comment: @FezVrasta Beside I have not the time to test that answer my self, I gave you a nice way to do it and the screenshots from all the browsers I have available, and forgot to shot `IE9+`, but shows up like in FF

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Ugly in which browsers...? My solution was consistent across all modern browsers. It also didn't require as much code.

Comment: I guess IE8-, I prefer set as answer this one that supports more browsers.

Comment: @JoshC in FF for instance, IE8 is horrible http://i.imgur.com/gOuCVkT.jpg And not to talk about all the other differences in width, line-height... etc across all other browsers...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Interesting. I am not getting the same results. Mine worked in the latest version of FF; unless you're referring to an older version?

Comment: Ok I'm having problems in get the same looks with your version, maybe is better set the JoshC answer as correct again :S http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bgicd

Comment: @FezVrasta of course, I'm not fighting for the green checkmark, I'm here to help you, and other people, to get the best result only with a suggestion of mine.

Comment: sure in fact I've set your as correct, but now I'm facing problems in use it for a not so flat project and your way looks not enough flexible (probably)

Comment: @FezVrasta you can make it flexible by just using `%` instead of `px` for the widths (count the paddings too) ;)

Comment: No I don't mean flexible in that way... I mean that it doesn't allow a lot of edits to its looks.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm not really fighting either, I just found it interesting how you stated, *"ya, tested the other answer, .... shows up pretty ugly. Your call."* as far as I can see, it actually works better.

Comment: Ok try to fix this one so: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bgicd I've edited the padding and now the button is not high as the input... Thanks

Comment: @JoshC for the sake of all the users that will find this question I agree to the best answer here! Hope you think the same! I'm just telling that I've opened IE8 with this demo of yours http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/s8Hzj/1/ and i've provided the screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/gOuCVkT.jpg

Comment: @FezVrasta If you take a closer look at what I did you'll notice that your `<span>` element does not have any border http://jsbin.com/OPiroyib/1/edit

Comment: Ok but I don't want the border on the entire element but just on 3 sides of the input :\ and to do this I need again the box-sizing so.

Comment: @FezVrasta So to resume the main point of main answer was following your picture, so that a `span` element can have a border that will encapsulate all your elements. Otherwise you could also not use any border at all, still shows fine in all browsers: http://jsbin.com/OPiroyib/2/edit

Comment: ahahah no this is not a real solution. I will keep your as the good one just because for a general use it's better, but for my purpose the one of JoshC is the right one.

Comment: @FezVrasta and if you want to add the border only to the text input than logically you need to add it to the button too: http://jsbin.com/OPiroyib/4/edit **Again crossbrowser.** So not only it's a crossbrowser solution but it's also really easy to edit and modify ;)

Answer (score 4):

You need to override the default `margin` on the `input` element too.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/77RfM/)

```
input, button {
    margin:0;
}
```

In doing so, there will no longer be space between the elements, assuming there is also no space between them in the markup. Note, that `inline` elements respect the whitespace in the markup.

For instance, even after resetting the default `margin` there is space between the elements, if there is space between them in the markup [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/a8yS4/)

---

For your second problem (making the elements the same height), do the following:

```
input, button {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align:top;
    line-height:30px;
    height:30px;
}
```

Basically, use `box-sizing` to change the box model, again reset the `margin`/`padding`, use `vertical-align:top` for alignment issues, and then set an equal `line-height`/`height` on both elements.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/s8Hzj/1/)

Comment: I don't think the padding should matter.

Comment: @AlexW It does matter for the heights of the elements - assuming you aren't changing the box model.

Comment: Thanks now is perfect. By the way using `box-sizing:border-box` the padding is counted so it doesn't matter. I'll wait a bit before set u as correct answer to see if someone has some better idea.

Comment: @JoshC It matters with the update where you are using `line-height` and `height`, but the padding should only affect alignment vertically.

Comment: @AlexW Yep you're right. I thought you were referring to the second issue when you stated that.

Comment: I've just noticed even the `line-height` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [css-reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to set the defaults in all browsers to "null".

Also css frameworks like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) are very cool!

Comment: I don't think "null" is valid CSS

Comment: I think it given the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a simple span tag instead of a button and then attach an onclick event to it?
The following seems to work ok for me - though you might need to use a reset / modenizer style sheet to make it more predictable on different browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/GRwqL/13/

```
<input class="nospace"></input><span class="nospace">Submit</span>

.nospace {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

span.nospace {
   height: 1em;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 1px;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Use the "button" element is semantically correct, a span element as button instead no. And both elements can be resetted to looks the same, so doesn't matter which kind of HTML element I use for the button.