# Make the textbox use the remaining space

Tags: html, css, css-position

Is it possible to dock the textbox to the button, so that it uses the remaining space (if possible without using absolute positioning)?

```css
#s{
  float: left;
  }

#b{
  float: right;
  }

#sb{
  width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Search</legend>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="s"><input id="sb" name="search"></input></div>
    <div id="b"><button>search</button> 
   </div>
 </fieldset>
```

Comment: How about using class `form-control` in the input?

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201848/clean-way-to-make-a-button-merged-with-input-text-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. Using `flex-box` will help.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
}
#s {
  flex: 1;
}
#sb {
  width: 100%;
}
input::-moz-focus-inner,
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Search</legend>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="s">
      <input id="sb" name="search">
    </div>
    <div id="b">
      <button>search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: It renders a bit oddly on FF, as the search button overlaps the textbox.  Maybe remove the float tags?

Comment: It's happening because of default properties of button element according to different browsers.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey don't forget to close `</div>` on `.container`

Comment: @AbhishekPandey also something among `input::-moz-focus-inner,
button::-moz-focus-inner{ 
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}` could help

Answer (score 0):

```css
#s{
  margin-right:80px;
  }

#b{
  float: right;
  width:70px;
  }

#sb{
  width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Search</legend>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="b"><button>search</button></div> 
    <div id="s"><input id="sb" name="search"></input></div>
    
   
 </fieldset>
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I'm going to guess it got downvoted because it's not very responsive.  For example, if #b was to change widths in the future, you must update #s's margin right to accommodate for it.  You could probably avoid this if you specifically mention that one downside.  I didn't downvote though since it's still a solution that can work on older browsers.